# Old versus new foreach loop

Tags: foreach, lambda, java-8, java-stream

In what cases should we use the older `foreach` loop over the new `collection.forEach()` in JDK 8 or is it best practice to convert *every* `foreach` loop? Are there any important performance differences?

The only case I can think of is if you want to iterate over an array and don't want to convert your array to a list first.

Comment: Note, `forEach()` has been moved to `Iterable` but it is still inherited by `Collection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to think of best practices at this point since JDK 8 hasn't even shipped yet. However, there are some interesting observations based on early use of these APIs.

The `forEach()` method is now on `Iterable`, which is inherited by `Collection`, so all collections can use `forEach()`.

An array can be wrapped in a collection with `Arrays.asList()` or in a stream with `Arrays.stream()`. These are just wrappers; they don't copy all the elements into a new container.

Regarding performance, the default implementation of `Iterable.forEach(action)` is simply the usual "enhanced for-loop" which creates an iterator and issues successive `hasNext()` and `next()` calls and calls to the `action` method within a loop. There is a little bit of extra overhead for the extra method calls, compared to a bare enhanced-for loop, but it's probably very small.

I would make a choice on stylistic grounds, not performance.

It's probably not worth it to convert *every* enhanced-for loop to use `forEach()`. Consider:

```
for (String s : coll) {
    System.out.println("---");
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("---");
}
```

versus

```
coll.forEach(s -> {
    System.out.println("---");
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("---");
});
```

If the lambda is a true one-liner it might be worth it, but in my opinion a multi-line statement lambda within `forEach()` isn't any clearer than a nice for-loop.

However, if the body of the for-loop has logic in it, or if it needs to maintain some kind of running state, it might be worthwhile to recast the loop into a stream pipeline. Consider this snippet that finds the length of the longest string in a collection:

```
int longest = -1;
for (String s : strings) {
    int len = s.length();
    if (len > longest)
        longest = len;
}
```

Rewritten using lambdas and the streams library, it would look like this:

```
OptionalInt longest =
    strings.stream()
           .mapToInt(s -> s.length())
           .max();
```

This is new and unfamiliar, of course, but after working with this for a while, I find it to be concise and readable.

Comment: How about the advantages of creating a parallelStream() or a stream() and then invoking forEach on it?

Comment: Yes, using a stream certainly affords easier parallelism. However, the original question was about `Collection.forEach` (really, `Iterable.forEach`) which is implicitly sequential, ordered, and has side-effects. Changing a straight for-each loop into a parallel stream might involve a lot of work, and it isn't necessarily an easy refactoring.